# Docker Swarm - Health check on a swarm node

Tags: docker-swarm

Is it possible for a swarm node to monitor itself, and set itself to drain under certain conditions? Much like `HEALTHCHECK` from Dockerfile, I'd like to specify the script that determines the node's health condition.

[Edit] For instance, this just started occurring today:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to update the store state of sandbox: 
    failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.sbState: invalid character 'H'
    looking for beginning of value.
```

I know how to *fix* this particular problem, but the node still reported `Ready` and `Active`, and was accepting tasks it could not run. A health check would have been able to determine the node could not run containers, and disable the node.

How else can you achieve a self-healing infrastructure?

Comment: How do you currently determine that this issue has occurred? This health check approach may be specific to your use case and not be generic

Comment: When we notice services not responding, we log into a manager and do `docker service ls`. If we see replicas missing on a service, we `docker service ps` to determine why, and which node it is failing on. Sometimes we will see status `Starting 4 hours ago`, or weird behavior like that, but ultimately we look for a pattern. Some times we've seen the /run volume filling up on a node with no files to explain the usage, or obscene CPU usage on processes that are primarily idle.  It feels like we're chasing ghosts sometimes.. But if the system is self-healing, we wouldn't be so worried about it.

Comment: And btw what are the healing steps?

Comment: Often turning it off and turning it on again. But if something becomes corrupt, then I'll have to delete /var/lib/docker/swarm, or in worse cases /var/lib/docker, and rejoin the node to the swarm.